# Laravel Nova tool wouldn't update if symlink is set to true on composer.json

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

So I am running into a weird issue. I used Laravel Nova (2) command to generate a tool. It sits at `./nova-components/CustomNovaDashboard`. In order for the deployment to work on Laravel Vapor, I had to add the below to my parent `composer.json`.

```
{
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./nova-components/CustomNovaDashboard",
            "options": {
                "symlink": false
            }
        }
```

This above allows the code to get deployed, because the absence of `symlink` in `options` would otherwise throw the following error:

```
include(/tmp/vendor/composer/../acme/custom-nova-dashboard/src/ToolServiceProvider.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

But the problem now is that when I run `npm run watch` inside `./nova-components/CustomNovaDashboard`, the code in development never updates, because somehow there is a copy of the code that sits in `vendor/acme/custom-nova-dashboard` that doesn't pick up the changes.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, it was quite simple.

In my `vapor.yml`, I had to add `COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1` before `composer install`.

```
build:
      - 'COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1 composer install'
      - 'php artisan event:cache'
      - 'npm ci && npm run dev && rm -rf node_modules'
```

This ensures the symbolic link generated by `nova:tool` works on `dev` and `prod` similarly.

Just don't forget to set `"symlink": true` in your `composer.json`. Or leave it as is originally generated by the `nova:tool` command.